# react-native-sound in componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I want to play music in componentDidMount but my code doesn't works

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'
const play = new Sound('music.mp3')

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
          play.play()
  }
  render(){ 
    return(
      <Nav />
    )
  }}
export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs you should use the callback in the constructor:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const play = new Sound('music.mp3', (error, play) => {
      if (error) return
      else play.play(() => {
        play.release() // release when done to release resources
      })
    })
  }
  render(){ 
    return(
      <Nav />
    )
  }}
export default App
```

Comment: What's `release when done to release resources` means?